# Is the following a property of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {${v_j}$} be a complete orthonormal set of a hilbert space and $a_i,b_j $ are scalars,then is the following true?
$\left\langle {\sum_i {a_i v_i} \sum_j {b_j v_j},v_i} \right\rangle = \sum_i a_i \sum_j b_j \left\langle {v_i v_j,v_i} \right\rangle$.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The first component (sum) in the scalar product on the left hand side looks strange.

Comment: So, is that not possible ?

Comment: If $ \left\langle {\cdot,\cdot} \right\rangle$ denotes the inner product, what is then the meaning of $v_iv_j$ ?

Comment: yeah true. How can we simplify LHS.Is that possible or is there something wrong in the understanding of  concept ?

Comment: yeah true ???? Once again: what is the meaning of $v_iv_j$ ?

Comment: No way to simplify LHS as the meaning of $v_iv_j$ is unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry,but I got confused.I thought of $v_i$ 's to be function,so we can find the product of 2 functions. And integral of the first function times  conjugate of second function is the inner product. But I really got confused about the difference between inner product and product of two function in an inner product space.

Comment: Can someone provide a clarification to my doubt? If we consider in $R^n$ dot product is a special case of inner product. In a function space how is product of two functions and inner product of two functions different? Can both be defined ?